# SceneKit: sceneView projectPoint with multiple cameras

Tags: swift, scenekit

If a scene contains multiple cameras, which camera does the `projectPoint` method use to project points from 3D to screen-space? If this is defined by the `pointOfView` property, then how come when I update the position of the `pointOfView` a given 3D point is still projected to the same 2D point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SCNCamera belongs to SCNView, just set the `PoV` via the "pointOfView" instance property of a View to a required camera node.

```
let cameraNode001 = SCNNode()
cameraNode001.camera = SCNCamera()
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode001)
cameraNode001.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

let cameraNode002 = SCNNode()
cameraNode002.camera = SCNCamera()
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode002)
cameraNode002.position = SCNVector3(x: 10, y: 10, z: 30)

let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView 
sceneView.scene = scene


sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode001
```

then you can change PoV:

```
sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode002
```